# Checkbox manipulation with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Hello I have a problem with checkboxes in my app.
I want to set value of layer visibility to false when other layer visibility is true and also set checkbox value to checked when visibility of layer is true. I have problem with .click function - console throws me typeError checkbox[i].click is not a function.

```
var changeLayer = function() {
    if (layers[0].M.visible == true) {
        layers[1].M.visible == false
    } else if (layers[0].M.visible == false) {
        layers[1].M.visible == true
    }
    if (layers[1].M.visible == true) {
        layers[0].M.visible == false
    } else if (layers[1].M.visible == false) {
        layers[0].M.visible == true
    }
}

var checkbox = $('.layer');
for (i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    checkbox[i].click(changeLayer);
//$(checkbox[i]).on('click', changeLayer)
}
```

Here is image of layer switcher where after click on first layer, second one should hide and uncheck the box.

[image: Map layer switcher]

I know that is maybe silly question, but I couldn't find solution. I hope you can help me.

Comment: You are looking for `onclick`.

Comment: or the jquery way $(checkbox[i]).on('click', function)

Comment: I tried with both onclick and jquery on.('click', function) but after click on item there was no response.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but you could simplify it quite a bit. The following will bind the same event to all elements with the class 'layer'.

`$('.layer').click(changeLayer);`

We'll probably need some more context to provide better solutions. As an FYI `.click(someHandler)` is just a shortcut for `.on('click', someHandler)`, they are the same.